# Intellij idea do not redirect to the root of the project

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, intellij-idea

Let's say I have a project named **project**. When I open the index.html using intellij built-in server it shows the url *localhost:port/project/index.html*
However, when I click on a  element that has *href="/"* it shows the url *localhost:port/index.html* causing css not to be applied and other issues. It works fine if I use  *href="/project"*. What could I do?

This project is hosted by github pages and works fine with just "/". So far, to work locally, I made a js script that replace slashes with /project (I know, not elegant and efficient..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leading slashes in URL tell the browser to resolve URLs from the web server root. But the built-in web server serves files from `http://localhost:63342/<project name>`, so no resources can be loaded from `http://localhost:63342` - thus the issue. There is unfortunately no way to set it up to use project root as server document root. I can only suggest using URLs relative to current `.html` file instead of URLs with leading slashes, or use a different web server to host your apps.

Note that we have added some fixes recently that make (most) of absolute paths work on the built-in web server, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11949/simplify-built-in-web-server-document-root-configuration#focus=Comments-27-5029164.0-0. But some problems still remain, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57280/Built-in-web-server-URL-links-in-CSS-dont-work-if-CSS-is-loaded-using-absolute-path-with-leading-slash, for example